# Accessing object literals in Javascript

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

This code is an example from Marionette:

```
AppLayout = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend(
{
    template: "#layout-template",

    regions: 
    {
        menu: "#menu",
        content: "#content"
    }
});

var layout = new AppLayout();

layout.menu.show(new MenuView());
layout.content.show(new MainContentView());
```

The last two lines confuse me.  Why doesn't it read:

```
layout.regions.menu.show(new MenuView());
layout.regions.content.show(new MainContentView());
```

Can someone please explain why layout.menu works and layout.regions.menu doesn't?

What if I wanted to access template?  Wouldn't that be layout.template?  template and regions are at the same depth inside layout.

Here is the constructor function from the marionette code:

```
// Ensure the regions are avialable when the `initialize` method
        // is called.
        constructor: function () {
            this._firstRender = true;
            this.initializeRegions();

            var args = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments);
            Marionette.ItemView.apply(this, args);
        },
```

Comment: Log the objects and inspect them!

Comment: child {_firstRender: true, regionManagers: Object, menu: Marionette.Region, content: Marionette.Region, render: function…}
$el: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1]
_events: Object
_firstRender: true
_listenerId: "l12"
_listeners: Object
cid: "view11"
content: Marionette.Region
el: "#content"
getEl: function (selector){
options: Object
__proto__: Object
el: div
menu: Marionette.Region
el: "#menu"
getEl: function (selector){
options: Object
__proto__: Object
options: Object
regionManagers: Object
render: function bound() {
__proto__: Surrogate

Comment: Sorry but there isn't a code view on comments.

Comment: wrap your text in back-ticks, `it will render a codeview`

Comment: here it is in back ticks `child {_firstRender: true, regionManagers: Object, menu: Marionette.Region, content: Marionette.Region, render: function…}
$el: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1]
_events: Object
_firstRender: true
_listenerId: "l12"
_listeners: Object
cid: "view11"
content: Marionette.Region
el: "#content"
getEl: function (selector){
options: Object
__proto__: Object
el: div
menu: Marionette.Region
el: "#menu"
getEl: function (selector){
options: Object
__proto__: Object
options: Object
regionManagers: Object
render: function bound() {
__proto__: Surrogate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it was implemented that way because 'layout.menu' is shorter and simpler than 'layout.regions.menu'. Looks like you expected the literal "#menu" to be replaced with a region manager object.

The options you passed in when creating the view, including the template, can be found in layout.options.  So in your case layout.options.template should equal '#layout-template', and the regions definition hash would be at layout.options.regions... still the same level.

Comment: I agree that  'layout.menu' is shorter and simpler than 'layout.regions.menu' but normally a programer doesn't have the ability to make things the way they want vs the way "it has to be".

Comment: So are you saying that the curly braces inside the extend parens is passed as an option to the extend method? .extend(
{
    template: "#layout-template",

    regions: 
    {
        menu: "#menu",
        content: "#content"
    }
});

Comment: If that is the case then that might explain my confusion.  I'm thinking that the structure .extends({...this stuff in here ...}) is how it will be in the constructed object but if it is actually just an options object passed into the extends method I can understand how it could be how the developer wanted it.

Comment: I added the constructor method to the question.  I am thinking that your idea of stuff being passed in makes sense but I don't see how.  Shouldn't it be in the constructor?

Comment: I'm looking at the code and I do see an arguments literal, that is what I would have passed in, except that it doesn't get used until after the initializeRegions() method is called.  And the answer is my structure is just for input.  The Marionette class has its own structure.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is more to the example then you are showing like the `Backbone.Marionette.Layout` methods, then its not accessing `regions.menu` like you think it is.

With just the code you have provided the code above is actually creating a `menu` attribute, which then has a `show` attribute so your `layout` object would actually look like this:

```
layout {
    menu : {
        show : new MenuView
    },
    content : {
         show : new MainContentView
    },

    template: "#layout-template",

    regions: 
    {
        menu: "#menu",
        content: "#content"
    }
}
```

In javascript the `(dot)` operator can be used to access a property of an attribute or if no property with that name exists then it will create that property.

I'm not familiar with the `backbone.js` framework but my guess is that they provide for skipping part of the [property lookup chain.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) which means that the above would end up producing this as your layout object:

```
 layout {
    template: "#layout-template",

    regions: 
    {
        menu : {
            show : new MenuView
        },
        content : {
            show : new MainContentView
        }
    }
}
```

But again that's just a guess on my part since I don't use `backbone`.

You can learn more about the [object model and how it works with inheritance right here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model)

Comment: Here is the link from where I got the example: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.layout.md

Comment: @KingAndrew  So I was correct; when you call `layout.render()` it gives the `layout` direct access to all `regions` so you then would end up with something like my second code example.

Comment: I looked at the code and it had this comment: // Initialize the regions that have been defined in a
            // `regions` attribute on this layout. The key of the
            // hash becomes an attribute on the layout object directly.
            // For example: `regions: { menu: ".menu-container" }`
            // will product a `layout.menu` object which is a region
            // that controls the `.menu-container` DOM element.

Comment: The comments confirm what is happening.  It looks like everything in the extends({..this stuff..}) is passed in like @John Mathis says but I don't see an options object in the constructor function.